# Prepopulate Rails form field with next integer value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, methods

In my nested attribute portion of a Rails form, I want to pre-populate the label for a form with the next integer (so input 1 would be #1, input 2 #2). Seems pretty straightforward, but I have not been successful using `i+1` like so:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :points_allocations, PointsAllocation.new do |points, i| %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= points.label "points_#{i+1}" %>
        <%= points.number_field :place, class: "form-control" %>
      </td>
  </tr>
 <% end %>
```

In turn, I get the error `undefined method`+' for nil:NilClass`.

This is confusing to me, as I don't understand why it's calling a method here instead of applying the math logic to add 1 to the previous integer.

What would be a better way to construct this form?

Comment: please accept my answer because it seemed to helped you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert `i` to integer:

```
 <%= points.label "points_#{i.to_i+1}" %>
```

Comment: Nailed it. Good catch. I should have checked that.

Answer (score 1):

`i` is `nil` in your code, hence the error.

Try this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :points_allocations, PointsAllocation.new do |points| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= points.label "points_#{points.index + 1}" %>
      <%= points.number_field :place, class: "form-control" %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Which version of Rails are you using?